# Explain different console.log values at same places in this example

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, scope

In the following snippet, while `console.log` is same for the same code, why is it providing 2 different results while calling as function, making new object? I know that functions have their own scope in JS, so at-least console.log inside a function should have rendered same result for both cases. Why, the 2 results are different?

Also, how the hell is scope inside a function is taking window scope rather than its own (functions have their own scope, should this should not be same as window object).

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <script>
    e = 50;

    function alpha() {
      this.a = 10;
      this.b = 20;
      this.e;
      console.log(this.e);
    }

    alpha();
    var b = new alpha;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

> **Note**: The duplicate question is general questioning not related to this code. I am asking for this particular problem, and is not
>   explained in duplicate link. Pls, reopen.

Comment: In first case `this` is `window` and in second case it is `alpha`

Comment: `this` and scope are different things.

Comment: Because just calling a function does not *make a `new` object*?

Comment: You can call the receiver (`this`) "context", but not "scope" please.

Comment: Have you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26574449) on that duplicate page? It covers everything including the 2 cases present in this question. Why REOPEN?